# App getting freezed for 30-40 seconds

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm getting blocked UI even parent-child method used for coredata background saving. App getting freezed for 30-40sec. I have tried GCD but it still getting stuck. Is there any way to remove that?

```
  **appdelegate**
  - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
 {


if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}


NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    //        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Before savings to DB i used to call another function which saves to dictionary.

```
   -(void)updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails:(NSDictionary *)inDictionary
  {


NSLog(@"updateSolicitationWithSyncDetails CALLED");

//NSDictionary *loDIct = [inDictionary objectForKey:@"body"];
NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:inDictionary];
NSString *userEmail=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

[paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSystemMessage"];
[paramDict setObject:userEmail forKey:@"userEmail"];

if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"d-activities"])
{
    NSMutableArray *activityArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"d-activities"]];
    //TODO:Check type
    [self manageActivityArrayWithDetails:activityArray ForType:@"Domain"];
}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"g-activities"])
{
    NSMutableArray *activityArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"g-activities"]];
    //TODO:Check type
    [self manageActivityArrayWithDetails:activityArray ForType:@"Feedback"];
}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"p-activities"])
{
    NSMutableArray *activityArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"p-activities"]];
    //TODO:Check type
    [self manageActivityArrayWithDetails:activityArray ForType:@"Private"];
}


if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"replies"])
{
    [paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"replies"] integerValue]] forKey:@"responseCount"];
}
NSDate *threadDate=[NSDate date];

if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"created_at"])
{
    double timeInMilliSeconds =[[inDictionary objectForKey:@"created_at"] doubleValue];
    threadDate=[[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] retrieveDateFromInterval:timeInMilliSeconds];//Convert timeinterval to date
}
[paramDict setObject:threadDate forKey:@"threadDate"];
[paramDict setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"receivedDate"];
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"_id"])
{
    [paramDict setObject:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"thread"];
    [paramDict setObject:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"solicitation"];

}
if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"owned"])
{
    BOOL isOwned=[[inDictionary valueForKey:@"owned"] boolValue];
    if(isOwned)
    {
        [paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isRequester"];
    }
    else
    {
        [paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isProvider"];

    }



}

if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"body"])
{

    NSString *message=[[inDictionary objectForKey:@"body"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    BOOL isDuplicate=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] checkForExistenceOfThreadDetailsForSolicitationID:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"_id"]];


    if(!isDuplicate)
    {
       // int randomIndex=[[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] getIndexForColorImageForTab:@"OUT"];
        [paramDict setObject:message forKey:@"threadDescription"];

        //[paramDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomIndex] forKey:@"colorCode"];
        [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] insertToThreadEntityWithData:paramDict];
    }
    else
    {
        [paramDict setObject:message forKey:@"messageDescription"];
        ThreadInfo *threadInfo=[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] retrieveSolicitationInfoForThreadID:[inDictionary objectForKey:@"_id"]];
        [paramDict setObject:threadInfo.threadID forKey:@"thread"];
        [[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:paramDict];
    }

   }



   }
```

insertToThreadEntityWithData

```
       AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectContext *contextforThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

contextforThread.parentContext = context;

[contextforThread performBlock:^{

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:threadPredicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

ThreadInfo *threadInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

for (UserInfo *info in fetchedObjects)
{

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
        }
    }

    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"thread"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.threadID=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"];
        }
    }

          NSError *error;
    if(![contextforThread save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Child error : %@",error);

    }

    [context performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
  }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are making a number of fundamental errors.

The error that is blocking your app UI is that you tie your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to the main thread. Your UI works on the main thread. So the PSC must work with and alongside the main UI operations.

You should consider creating two `NSManagedObjectContext`s at the time you instantiate your MOC & PSC.

- One based on `initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`
- One based on `initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`

You use the main queue managed object context (MOC) to handle small and frequent saves of data changes in MOC in the main thread (to memory) thereby reducing to negligible the effect saving has on the UI.

You use the private queue MOC to persist the data to disk on a background thread - no effect on UI.

For this to be effective, you'll need to:

- tie your PSC to your private MOC,
- make the private MOC the parent of the main MOC,
- persist user changes to data within the main MOC,
- if necessary, persist imported and/or large data sets within an additional "local" MOC, that is a child of the main MOC, and
- write a custom save method.

See the save block I wrote in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514323/cant-create-externaldatareference-interim-file/29536824%2329536824).

Go see how one of the masters of Core Data does it... [Marcus Zarra's entry in the Martiancraft Blog](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/)... I learned all I know on the subject from reading his 2013 book on Core Data.

Comment: I have already used parent-child threading, but still have stuck.

Comment: Sure, you have used parent child threading - in a convoluted manner. If you are always correct then why ask for assistance? What I am suggesting is much simpler than the convoluted mechanism you have implemented.

Comment: I am not that much experienced with multi threading. can you just modify my code ? So that i can get the real issues of mine.

Comment: Your response is simply inappropriate. This is a site dedicated to help people learn to solve problems, not solve the problems for them. I've provided more than enough information to help you solve your multi-threading issue. There is a huge volume on this site alone to help you. Beyond that the links to Marcus Zarra's blog are all you need to learn. So learn!